# Change direciton to the left when AddView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

[image]

is it possible if change the direction when I add view in LinearLayout to the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `layoutDirection` attribute.  In your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

`"rtl"` in this case means "right to left."

The implementation for what you're trying to do would consist of one vertical `LinearLayout` with two horizontal `LinearLayout`s as its children.

Comment: It requires API level 17. I created app with min API level 10.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.  For the right to left row, you can use a `RelativeLayout` instead.  For the rightmost view, specify `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`.  For each subsequent view, specify `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/previousViewId"`, where `previousViewId` is actually specified in the XML for each view, for example `android:id="@+id/view1"`.  That should get the job done.